# PHP Version Check Magento 2

Tags: magento2, composer

I am trying to update my Magento 2 to the latest version, my system fails the readiness check with the below message:

> PHP Version Check Your PHP version is . The required PHP version is .
>   Hide detail
>
> Download and install PHP from www.php.net using this PHP
>   Documentation.
>
> For additional assistance, contact your hosting provider.

I understand this error might be linked to the SSL. Magento 2 by default uses ssl. I don't use ssl on my localhost and this error arises. I have to edit the config section of composer.json file in the root of magento. My composer.json must exist in this folder:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer
```

It is not there. I have installed a composer file but I cannot change the .phar to .json to do the needful. Whenever I save this in .txt then in .json I get strange characters in the file like Τ�Yb �c�߶

How can I get the right composer.json file to change `"disable-tls":true` as per the below illustration?

Method 1: Disable-tls parameter:

```
"config": {
  "use-include-path": true 
  "disable-tls":false
},
```

Method 2: Without disable-tls parameter (delete the line):

```
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true,
},
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running for this install, you should be running 70 or higher.

Comment: Thanks! I am using PHP Version 5.6.31. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your php version using the following tutorial:

http://www.techflirt.com/how-to-upgrade-php7-in-xampp

Comment: Thanks! I miss one thing. I have copied the old PHP file and created a backup of that. In the same PHP folder, I have copied the most recent PHP version (7.1.8) to the current PHP folder and replaced existing files. I understand that there are two directories to be updated with new version of files, namely (php) sub-directory and (apache/bin) sub-directory, inside XAMPP installation. I cannot find the files I have to copy inside the (apache/bin) sub-directory. Where can I get those from?